# Visual Studio Code breakpoint appearing in wrong place

Tags: debugging, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuex

In my Vue+Vuex project, I am trying to debug using Visual Studio Code.  I have the debugger launching properly using Chrome debug tools, and properly using a map, but when I try to place breakpoints in my .js or .vue files, VS Code seems to be placing the breakpoints in the wrong place.  For example, here I try to place a breakpoint in one of my getters on line 40, but it ends up 15 lines later:

[image]

Is this a bug in VS Code, or perhaps some other issue?  Any suggestions on how to fix?

Other breakpoints on other lines have the same behavior of appearing on later lines, but I cannot detect a pattern.  It happens in both .js and .vue files, and it happens both in Object declarations and root-level traditional function definitions.

I am using VS Code 1.24.0.

Comment: Possible to share a project so we know we are using the same stuff as you are?

Comment: I don't think I can share this whole thing...sorry.

Comment: I meant a minimal project which shows your issue

Comment: For similar VS Code problem with typescript I had to add "sourceMap": true to tsconfig.json as advised in [how to debug typescript files in visual studio code](//stackoverflow.com/a/51080377)

Comment: I had the same issue. For example, I placed breakpoint in line 37, but when debugger executes, the breakpoint was moved to line 35. So I clicked on line 37 to put the bp where it should be, then the bp in 35 goes off, though execution stops in 35 instead of 37.... it was driving me crazy. So I opted to completely remove all breakpoints from the list, uninstall VScode, restart my computer, install a fresh version of VSCode again, dl a complete new fresh version of the code.... and that seems to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 64):

To answer this for any particular case, one would need the `launch.json` configuration being used, and the source folder structure, at minimum.  I have a true story from just last week to illustrate why:

**Background**

I recently inherited a relatively small Vue project, and immediately encountered the same problem.  Breakpoints in VSCode were "jumpy" in all my source files.

The project wasn't developed in VSCode, so there was no `launch.json` in source control.  My first naive attempt at a debug configuration looked like this:

```
{
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch Chrome",
  "url": "http://localhost:8080",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "sourceMaps": true
}
```

One very important detail is the source folder structure.  It looks like this:

```
D:\TST\PROJECT
└───src
    │   main.js
    │
    ├───components
    │       AnotherComponent.vue
    │       SomeComponent.vue
    │
    └───services
            myservice.js
            yourservice.js
```

---

**Fixing it**

The easy to find problem was the `webRoot`.  Since my source files were all in a `src` folder, this needed to point to `${workspaceRoot}/src`, instead of just `${workspaceRoot}`.  Just doing this fixed all the jumpiness in my `.vue` files under `src/components`.  Unfortunately, breakpoints in `main.js` and in the files in the `services` folder were still jumpy.

The next step was to add a `sourceMapPathOverrides` key to the launch.json configuration.  VSCode autocompletes what I believe are the default values:

```
  "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
    "webpack:///./*": "${webRoot}/*",
    "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
    "webpack:///*": "*",
    "webpack:///./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*",
    "meteor://app/*": "${webRoot}/*"
  }
```

I left these as they were, and added two entries.  To fix `main.js`, I added:

`"webpack:///./src/*": "${webRoot}/*",`

and to fix the files in the services folder I added:

`"webpack:///./src/services/*": "${webRoot}/services/*",`

At this point all my breakpoints behaved in all my files throughout the project.

---

**But Why?**

Unfortunately I can't tell you why these two magic lines are needed in my case, or even what they really do.

However, I can tell you how I divined them.  In Chrome's devtools, I drilled into the `webpack://` section of the "Sources" tab.  I noticed that `src/components` was showing in the "root", (green arrow), and my other sources (red arrows) were not.  They were only showing under `.` (circled red).

[image: Chrome devtools sources tab showing webpacked sources]

*Disclaimers*: I'm not an expert in Vue, webpack, chrome debugging protocol, sourcemaps, or vue-loader.  I'm just one more developer who wants to set his breakpoints in his IDE, not his browser.

Comment: I had done everything you did, apart from the **sourceMapPathOverrides** property in the `launch.config` file. Adding that made the breakpoint stop sliding to weird places.

Comment: I've added the sourceMapPathOverrides as posted here (except for the meteor part) to replace the ones specified in the Vue HOWTO and it fixed the breakpoint issue as posted by OP. Thanks for this

Comment: Really one of the most helpful answers I've ever seen about IDE tools on SO!  Provided both a correct fix and (more usefully), a technique for a non-expert to use to recognize similar problem.

Comment: Note that 1) `${workspaceRoot}` [has been deprecated](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_why-isnt-workspaceroot-documented) in favor of `${workspaceFolder}` and 2) the folder you have open in VS Code is very relevant to getting this right. If you are opened at a higher-level folder, then `${workspaceRoot}/src` will not point to the right place. This answer was very helpful

Comment: This answer is not actually what the questioner asks about. The issue seems to be from mapping issue.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe editor and debugger are not using the same interpretation of "newline". Check if the code uses \r or \r\n and change it to the other.

Comment: Thank you for this. I had no idea this was used setting/removing breakpoints. Had been struggling for days!

Comment: In my case, I had Git checked out with `core.autocrlf=false` on Windows due to my change during the installer. Changing it with `git config --global core.autocrlf true` and deleting and checking out the repo again fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After some intense minutes where I questioned my very existence and started working on my master plan to burn Microsoft to the ground I got to the bottom of it

### Issue:

Some of my breakpoints were jumpy but only when I actually executed the code and debugger was attached. I could set it well when not running the code, but as I ran it they got scrambled.

### Solution:

.js and .ts files were being mapped wrongly so I just had to
`npm run build`
and voila

Answer (score 1):

I just found what was the bug for me. When you delete lines your binary dont know and the debugger take the lines on that not on what it is display on your window. So you just have to remake your binary with the change of lines.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** - make sure your code is actually being referenced/called

In my case:

- node.js server app
- set breakpoint on line 209 (the first statement in method 'InsertClients')

The IDE would automatically move the breakpoint to the bottom of the file, line 649.

WTF!?

I finally found out: its because I'd named the method incorrectly: 'InsertClients' instead of 'InsertClient'

So the IDE must have been wiggin' out that the code would never get executed and therefore placed the breakpoint on the next piece of code that would get executed after the method definition...which was the close brace of the app (or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

Adding `"sourceMaps": true,` to `launch.json` fixed this.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are actually trying to set break point at the middle of a statement.

It is actually a single statement.

Consider below statement.

You can set a break point infront of it.

> `var obj = { a: value1, b: value2 }`

If you write this as

```
var obj = { //can set break point here
 a: value1, //you can't set break point in this line 

 b: value2 //you can't set break point in this line 
}
```