# how to add all folders in webpack source

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vscode-debugger

i have a vuejs project structure which look like

[image]

when served through vue-cli-service, the source tab from devtool has only

[image]

so when i try to add breakpoint to other files in the src/ like filters,utils,...

it's not working(becomes unbound breakpoint), is there any way to add entire src/ to webpack.

`debugger` statement works but not vscode breakpoint

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're solving it from the wrong side. That you see this suggests that these files weren't added to the bundle because they aren't in use. If you're sure this is not so, try to add `debugger` statement to a file that's not listed and see how it appears at breakpoint

Comment: when i add `debugger` statement in other files it stops,  but i can't able to set breakpoints in vscode. @EstusFlask

Comment: Is the file highlighted with the statement? Did you check how it works in browser devtools?

Comment: the file was not in *webback://src/*
it was in *webpack://./src/*

Comment: check this answer - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50765353/visual-studio-code-breakpoint-appearing-in-wrong-place/50826961#50826961

Comment: Glad you sorted this out. You may want to mark the question as duplicate, this may help other users who have the same problem